# Invariance of Particle Distribution in Heavy Ion Colissions

Tags: special-relativity, phase-space, heavy-ion

I'm reading about about Heavy Ion collisions from the book by Csernai and i can't make sense of the proof that the particle distribution $f(x,p)$ is an invariant scalar. Before i quote the book:

The particle four flow is: $N^\mu=(n(x),\vec{j}(x))$

The number of particles N in a phase space volume element: $N=f(x,p)\Delta^3x\Delta^3p$

and $N^{\mu}(x)=\int \frac{d^{3} p}{p^{0}} p^{\mu} f(x, p)$

At page 45 the book reads:

$\int 2 \delta\left(p^{\mu} p_{\mu}-m^{2}\right) \Theta\left(p^{0}\right) d^{4} p=$
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d p^{3} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d p^{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d p^{1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d p^{0} 2 \delta\left(p^{\mu} p_{\mu}-m^{2}\right) \Theta\left(p^{0}\right)$

Using
$$
\delta[\phi(x)]=\sum_{i} \frac{1}{\left|\phi^{\prime}\left(a_{i}\right)\right|} \delta\left(x-a_{i}\right)
$$

\begin{aligned}
&\text { where } a_{i} \text { is the root of } \phi(x), \text { (i.e. } \left.\phi\left(a_{i}\right)=0\right), \text { we can cast the } \delta \text { -function in the form }\\
&\delta\left(p^{\mu} p_{\mu}-m^{2}\right)=\delta\left(\left(p^{0}\right)^{2}-(\vec{p})^{2}-m^{2}\right)=\delta\left(\left(p^{0}\right)^{2}-\varepsilon^{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2 \varepsilon}\left[\delta\left(p^{0}-\varepsilon\right)+\delta\left(p^{0}+\varepsilon\right)\right]\\
&\text { where } \varepsilon=\sqrt{(\vec{p})^{2}+m^{2}} . \text { Thus: }
\end{aligned}

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2 \frac{1}{2 \varepsilon}\left[\delta\left(p^{0}-\varepsilon\right)+\delta\left(p^{0}+\varepsilon\right)\right] \Theta\left(p^{0}\right) d p^{0}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}=\frac{1}{p^{0}(\vec{p})}
$$
where $p^{0}(\vec{p})=\varepsilon=\sqrt{(\vec{p})^{2}+m^{2}}$ and
$$
\Theta\left(p^{0}\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1: & \text { if } p^{0} \geq 0 \\ 0: & \text { if } p^{0}<0\end{array}\right.
$$

Therefore
$$
N^{\mu}(x)=\int d^{4} p 2 \delta\left(p^{2}-m^{2}\right) p^{\mu} f(x, p) \Theta\left(p^{0}\right)=\int \frac{d^{3} p}{p^{0}} p^{\mu} f(x, p)
$$
where $\Theta\left(p^{0}\right)$ is the step function. Conclusion: $f(x, p)$ is an invariant scalar

I can follow the math step by step but i can't understand why any of this is counts as a proof. I understand that $p^\mu$ is a four vector and that $\frac{d^3p}{p^0}$ is an invariant scalar therefore we need $f(x,p)$ to be an invariant scalar also but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

What you mention at the end of your question is the correct answer. If $N^\mu$ and $p^\mu$ are the components of 4-vectors, and $\mathrm d^3p/p^0$ is a scalar, then $f(x,p)$ must be a scalar for consistency.

Comment: Hello and im sorry i took this long to answer, but i still don't understand where the step function is useful in all of this and why it's being used here in the first place

Comment: No problem! One uses the theta function to write the integral in a simpler way. It is clear that one has to integrate only for positive energies (*i.e.* $E=p^0>0$). This integral could be written as $\int_0^\infty \mathrm dE$, or as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm dE\Theta(E)$. The theta function would guarantee that the part with $E<0$ doesn't contribute to the integral. One might prefer this option since the integrals over $p^1$, $p^2$ and $p^3$ are between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. The inclusion of the theta function allows to write all integrals with the same integration limits.

Comment: But if you know that $\frac{d^3p}{p^0}$ is an invariant scalar and that $p^{\mu}$ is a four vector, can't we just conclude form these facts that $f(x,p)$ is an invariant scalar since $N^{\mu}$ is a four vector? Why go through all of these steps?